# Perl subroutine timeout

Tags: perl, time, timeout, ole, subroutine

I have a subroutine that normally takes 1 second to run. Sometimes, it can run infinitely. I want to move on in the code if the subroutine is taking too long (> 10 seconds) and ignore that run of that subroutine. Here is what I have so far using alarm.

```
use Win32::OLE;

eval { 
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" };
    alarm 10;                   # schedule alarm in 10 seconds 
    &do_the_subroutine;
    alarm 0;                    # cancel the alarm
};

if ($@) {
    $error_string .= $script;
    #Do something else if the subroutine took too long.
}

do_the_subroutine{
# use existing instance if Excel is already running
    eval {$ex = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')};
    die "Excel not installed" if $@;
    unless (defined $ex) {
        $ex = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;})
                or die "Oops, cannot start Excel";
    }

    # get a new workbook
    $book = $ex->Workbooks->Add;

    # write to a particular cell
    $sheet = $book->Worksheets(1);
    $sheet->Cells(1,1)->{Value} = "foo";

    # write a 2 rows by 3 columns range
    $sheet->Range("A8:C9")->{Value} = [[ undef, 'Xyzzy', 'Plugh' ],
                                       [ 42,    'Perl',  3.1415  ]];

    # print "XyzzyPerl"
    $array = $sheet->Range("A8:C9")->{Value};
    for (@$array) {
        for (@$_) {
            print defined($_) ? "$_|" : "<undef>|";
        }
        print "\n";
    }

    # save and exit
    $book->SaveAs( 'test.xls' );
    undef $book;
    undef $ex;
}
```

&do_the_subroutine never returns so I'm not able to move on. I'm also not able to put this block of code inside that subroutine. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you share the subroutine's code? It works fine for me, see this demo: http://ideone.com/KycD4S

Comment: I can't seem to recreate this behavior, using the same code I see the alarm going off. Is there more code that we are not seeing here? Can you show the definition of `do_the_subroutine`?

Comment: Hello, I have added the definition.

Comment: The OLE stuff looks like it could be slow.

Comment: @simbabque yes.. hence why I am doing this.

Comment: I wonder if the alarm signal thing is handled differently with Windows signals.

Comment: What is your question?  Would this be a better fit for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @pilcrow the question is: How to make it quit the subroutine after 10 seconds.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines @sobrique. But also maybe that it runs something external and for that the handler isn't invoked. So I tried to use `sub do_the_sub { system 'sleep 15' }` on my Linux box. Works just the same. No problems visible. We need a Windows box.

Comment: <sarcasm>Maybe if you change that comment from `schedule alarm in 15 seconds` to **10** seconds... </sarcam> :)

Comment: @pilcrow This question would be off-topic for CR. This is about hunting down a known bug and altering functionality of code. Please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, yes, thanks.  I'd misunderstood the OP's "&dosub never returns" remark to simply be a restatement of his "sometimes it can run infinitely."

Comment: FWIW http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=505473 also seems to indicate OLE doesn't play well with alarm.  perhaps move the work to a child process or a thread?

Comment: of course, the other question might be - _why_ does that sub 'stall' - it doesn't look like it should infinite loop or anything.

Comment: as to why it stalls, on my Windows box I got a pop-up from Microsoft Excel asking _"A file named 'test.xls' already exists in this location.  Do you want to replace it?"_.  I assume the hang is based on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that what you want to do is simply not natively possible with `alarm` on Windows.

From `perldoc perlport`:

> **alarm**   Emulated using timers that must be explicitly polled whenever
>             Perl wants to dispatch "safe signals" and therefore cannot
>             interrupt blocking system calls. (Win32)

Comment: Thought it might be something like that. Well done for doing the digging :)